# How to validate Radio button fields in form Either or OR?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a radio form elements with other fields as well on a webpage, there have two types of form radio field, one is vegetable and other is meat. I want to select like these "If they select a meat they have to select a veggie but if they only select a veggie they don't have to select a meat" here is the screenshot of these radio fields http://prntscr.com/nhu6ao
[image]

```
jQuery('.radio').change(function() {
  jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('error');
  jQuery(this).parent().parent().removeClass('error');
  if (jQuery(this).hasClass('box-input')) {
    jQuery('#preseason-error').slideUp("slow");
    jQuery('#preseason-title').css("color", "#444");
    jQuery('.boxes-select').removeClass('error');
  }
})
```

Results will be: If they select a meat they have to select a veggie but if they only select a veggie they don't have to select a meat

Comment: On an unrelated note to the question itself: You should make sure in your user interface that the user can deselect the meat option if they selected one by accident.

Comment: A note, you can combine the lines 2-3 into  `jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('error').parent().removeClass('error');` Also, I wouldn't validate against `class` but the actual state `.checked` and `.value`.

Comment: @MoshFeu actually most of the functionality working when click on submit button, you can check here https://stubbornfarmer.com/sign-me-up/ so we need little work on validation

Comment: So basically, veg is mandatory, while meat is not, right? If so, validate just veg radios..

Comment: just add required attribute to veggi radio and use html5--form-validation

Answer (score 0):

Voila!

I have prepped a simple example for you. Before we begin I would like to point out 2 things. It is very inefficient to create an event listener for every form element, as you did by calling the `.on('.radio')`. Good practice here is to add event listener on the form ( or any other wrapping element - even body ), and than use the `event.target` as your reference to the form element that was just clicked by the user.

Another thing is that from the UX perspective I would suggest moving the Meat dishes above the Veggies, as it does not make sense to show it as a first choice if Veggies are somehow dependant on Meats.

JSfiddle with working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mkbctrlll/7209ayr3/45/

```
const $meals = $('#meal-options')

$meals.on('change', function(event) {
    if(event.target.name === 'meat') {
    console.log('Meat selected!')
    $('input[name="veggie"]').attr('required', 'true')
  }
})
```

```
<form id="meal-options">
  <h2>
    Meat options
  </h2>

  <label for="radio-1">
    <input id="radio-1" name="meat" type="radio">
    Meat 1
  </label>

  <label for="radio-2">
    <input id="radio-2" name="meat" type="radio">
    Meat 2
  </label>

  <h2>
    Veggie options
  </h2>

  <label for="radio-3">
    <input id="radio-3" name="veggie" type="radio">
    veggie 1
  </label>

  <label for="radio-4">
    <input id="radio-4" name="veggie" type="radio">
    veggie 2
  </label>

  <label for="radio-5">
    <input id="radio-5" name="veggie" type="radio">
    veggie 3
  </label>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```